# Can 'look after', 'take care of' and 'care for' be used interchangeably in this context?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Here's the context:

I'm advising my students to keep their bodies clean to prevent themselves from diseases, lice, et cetera.

Of the three following sentences that refer to the importance of the practice of keeping themselves (and their living areas, where possible) clean in order to prevent illness, disease, et cetera, which is grammatically the best?

1. You have to look after your hygiene.
2. You have to take care of your hygiene.
3. You have to care for your hygiene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a native speaker, they all seem a little awkward. "You have to take care of your hygiene" is the most natural to me, though some better alternatives exist:

> You have to keep the area hygienic.

says you should clean the area so that it's to a level that can prevent illnesses.

> You have to maintain/have good hygiene.

"**Maintain**" implies that the area/person is already at a sufficient level of hygiene and just needs to try to keep it that way.

"**Have**" is looser, and does not assume sufficient hygiene like maintain.

> You have to maintain/have good personal hygiene.

This specifically refers to taking care of your body and keeping it clean.